# How do a build a custom ng-view directive, possibly using ng-includes?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating an app that has a detail view that appears as a modal window above a main view. Each has a URL, but if detail view is accessed from the URL directly I want it to be presented as the main view. This metaphor is used in many apps, but a pinterest pin is a classic example (try clicking a pin, and then reloading the page to see the difference).

From what I've gathered, the regular router is not powerful enough to handle this, so I've written my own directive to replace ng-view. Here's a simplified code sample:

```
app.directive('myModalView', ['$route', function($route) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var data = { modal: false };
      var first = true;
      scope.data = data;

      scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        var current = $route.current.$$route;
        var template = current.templateUrl;

        data.modal = current.modal && !first;
        data.modal ? data.modalTemplate = template : data.mainTemplate = template;  

        first = false;
      });
    },
    template: '<div ng-include src="data.mainTemplate"></div>' +
              '<div ng-show="data.modal" ng-include src="data.modalTemplate"></div>',
  };
}]);
```

Two questions:

- Is this the right approach? Is there a more 'angular' way to do this?
- The above code has a key problem -- if two URLs use the same template, the ng-include does not refresh. In some situations my controllers are checking for URL parameters on initializing and providing different data to the view. Is there a way to make the ng-include refresh, re-initialize the controller, or do something else to handle this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in checking out the [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) project, it aims to replace ng-view  with multiple nested or parallel ui-view elements